# Upload fails "move uploaded file"

Tags: php, upload

First off, the upload folder is given 777, and my old upload script works, so the server accepts files. How ever this is a new destination.

I use krajee bootstrap upload to send the files. And I receive a Jason response. The error seems to be around move uploaded file. I bet it's a simple error from my side, but I can't see it.

```
<?php
if (empty($_FILES['filer42'])) {
    echo json_encode(['error'=>'No files found for upload.']); 
    // or you can throw an exception 
    return; // terminate
}

// get the files posted
$images = $_FILES['filer42'];

// a flag to see if everything is ok
$success = null;

// file paths to store
$paths= [];

// get file names
$filenames = $images['name'];

// loop and process files
for($i=0; $i < count($filenames); $i++){
    $ext = explode('.', basename($filenames[$i]));
    $target = "uploads" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . md5(uniqid()) . "." . array_pop($ext);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filer42"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target)) {
        $success = true;
        $paths[] = $target;
    } else {
        $success = false;
        break;
    }
}
// check and process based on successful status 
if ($success === true) {.
    $output = [];

    $output = ['uploaded' => $paths];
} elseif ($success === false) {
    $output = ['error'=>'Error while uploading images. Contact the system administrator'];
    // delete any uploaded files
    foreach ($paths as $file) {
        unlink($file);
    }
} else {
    $output = ['error'=>'No files were processed.'];
}
// return a json encoded response for plugin to process successfully
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Comment: what is the error itself?

Comment: Why are you using two file names? 1.`$_FILES['filer42']`. & 2. `$_FILES['pictures']`.

Comment: `$target` returns `string(42) "uploads/a0029f80fce0bd52a982b0159af6e33d.0"`
But this have to be `.jpg` and not `.0` Going to look in to why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think field name is the issue. Because you are getting image name with `filer42` and upload time, you are using `pictures`.

Please change

`$_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$i]`

to

`$_FILES["filer42"]["tmp_name"][$i]`

And check now, Hope it will work. Let me know if you still get issue.

Comment: Changed. That was a fault from my side. Bit still not working. Trying to figure a way to get a error message from the server.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in this script but in the post. 
I was using `<input id="filer42" name="filer42" type="file">`
but it have to be `<input id="filer42" name="filer42[]" type="file" multiple>`
as the script seems to need an arrey.

It works just fine now.